# Failed to launch the browser process! when deploying node.js app on shared hosting

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer, cpanel, shared-hosting

So I built a simple project to test out and it works well on my local machine. the challenge comes when I deploy it on my Cpanel hosting I get an error A  `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Failed to launch the browser process!`

```
//app.json


const { Client } = require('whatsapp-web.js');
const http = require('http');

const hostname = '127.0.0.1';
const port = 3000;

const client = new Client();

client.on('qr', (qr) => {
    // Generate and scan this code with your phone
    console.log('QR RECEIVED', qr);
});

client.on('ready', () => {
    console.log('Client is ready!');
});

client.on('message', msg => {
    if (msg.body == '!ping') {
        msg.reply('pong');
    }
});

client.initialize();


const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
  res.statusCode = 200;
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
  res.end('Hello World');
});

server.listen(port, hostname, () => {
  console.log(`Server running at http://${hostname}:${port}/`);
});
```

```
// package.json


{
  "name": "puppet",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start" : "node app.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "whatsapp-web.js": "^1.12.0"
  }
}
```

everything installs correctly but when the app starts it writes this error in the log file

```
App 4096690 output: (node:4096690) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Failed to launch the browser process!
App 4096690 output: /home/linearcb/nodevenv/repositories/whatsapp/10/lib/node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium/linux-818858/chrome-linux/chrome: error while loading shared libraries: libatk-1.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Comment: I think it says what it's missing: `error while loading shared libraries: libatk-1.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`.

Comment: So it's not possible to run the project on a shared hosting?

Comment: You need to have all the dependencies installed, then you can run it wherever you want.